# ImpulseDE2, matrix counts contains non-integer elements

Tags: r, matrix, bioinformatics

Possibly it's a stupid question (but be patient, I'm a beginner in R's word)... I'm working with ImpulseDE2, a package designed to RNAseq data analysis along different times (see [article](http://biorxiv.org/content/early/2017/03/05/113548) for more information).

The running function (*runImpulseDE2*) requires a matrix counts and a annotation data frame. I've created both but it appears this error message:

*Error in checkCounts(matCountData, "matCountData"): ERROR: matCountData contains non-integer elements. Requires count data.*

I have tried some solutions and nothing seems to work (and I've not found any solution in the Internet)...

- as.matrix(data)
- (data + 1) > and there isn't NAs nor zero values that originate this error (`$ which(is.na(data))` and  `$ which(data < 1)`, but both results are `integer(0)`)
- as.numeric(data) > and appears another error: *ERROR: [Rownames of matCountData] was not given as input.*

I think that's something I'm not realizing, but I'm totally locked. Every tip will be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

And here is the (silly) solution! This function seems not to accept float numbers... so applying a simple *round* is enough to solve this error.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You dont have float numbers for count data. Use count data instead of rounding up something else